# Why points disappear when using Graphics function in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, drawing

I am doing a very basic operation -- drawing dots in Mathematica. Here's the code:

```
Graphics[
 {
  Point[{0, 0}], Point[{1, 2}]
  }
 ]
```

I gives the result that I wanted:

[image]

But when I specified the "PlotRange", I then got a blank canvas. Why the two dots disappeared?

```
Graphics[
 {
  Point[{0, 0}], Point[{1, 2}]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0}, {4, 4}}
 ]
```

Screenshot:

[image]

If you cannot reproduce the problem I encountered, please also let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option PlotRange was used wrong. You have to give the corners of the rectangular plot-range in this order `{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}`.

In your case

```
PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have been more careful.

Comment: As you can see the {0,0} point is cut in half. Before adjusting the PlotRange in your real program, maybe you should check the PlotRangePadding option.